# chrome return ajax https api calling 403 error but can open the api request successfully

Tags: ajax

the  ajax can be call through successfully both in firefox and chrome if the endpoint protocal is http

```
http://etender.glodon.com.sg/project/inquireList?t=0.6671383485217255
```

when the api change to https from http,  firxfox  has no problem.
In chrome the ajax request  will get a 403 error.

[image: chrome inspect]

```
go to inspect->network->xhr  
right clike the name:inquireList?t=0.6671383485217255 and open in new tab, 
the api return data as expect.
```

Comment: Did you try using Incognito mode of Google Chrome or a newer version? I tested the same api and everything seems to be fine in my browser.

Comment: i updated to 60.0.3112.78（official） （64 bit）and still has the same problem

Comment: Tried using someone else's system? As I can see it's a remote address, it is very much accessible by any other system.

Comment: yes, i have tried use chrome on others system, got 403 error too

Comment: This is what I get. Notice the difference? Yours is hitting a local URL instead of a remote URL. 52.76.121.216 is replaced by 192.168.0.119 in your request. Check it from some another network that isn't sharing the network with your local machine..for example cellular data in your mobile device.

Request URL:https://etender.glodon.com.sg/project/inquireList?t=0.6671383485217255

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200

Remote Address:52.76.121.216:443

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: the remote url will be 192.168.0.119 if i access the api via proxy, the remote URL will be 52.76.121.216 without proxy

Comment: May be the proxy is interfering with your website's behavior but I don't think that might happen until there's misconfiguration in proxy. I think the API works perfectly fine on other systems with chrome..check chrome settings for any proxy configuration.